# Select button from div inside dynamic table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add a click event handler for a button inside a div that is inside a table. How do I reach it using jQuery. Here is my div:

```
<div id = 'fromServer'></div>
```

Here is how I populate it:

```
function onSuccess(response) {
    p = response;   //p is global for debugging! 
    resultsArray = response.results;
    str = '<table id=\'mytable\'>';
    str += '<tr><td class =\'title\'>Album</td>';
    str += '<td class =\'title\'>Track Name</td>';
    str += '<td class =\'title\'> <button id =\'save\'>Save</button></td></tr>';

    for (i = 0; i < resultsArray.length; i++) {
        str += '<tr><td>' + '<img src=\'' + resultsArray[i].artworkUrl100 +'\' height=\'100\' width=\'100\''  +  '</td>';
        str += '<td class=\'albumName\'>'  + resultsArray[i].trackName.substring(0,30) + '</td>';
        str +=   '<td> <input type=\'checkbox\' class =\'checkbox\' name=\'' + i + '\'></td></tr>';
    }
    str += '</table>';
    $('#fromServer').html(str);
}
```

Here is how it looks:

[image]

Now I want to add a click event handler for the save button, how do I do that? Here is my attempt but it doesn't work.

```
$('#fromServer').find("#mytable").find("#save").bind('click', saveButtonEventHandler);

//Event Handlers
function saveButtonEventHandler(evt) {
    alert("Button pressed!");
}
```

Comment: FYI Did you know you can also use jQuery to construct dynamic html?  For example `var myTable = $('<table>');`  All the attributes, properties can be set in the same way.  It is more readable syntax IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the fact that the table and save button are being dynamically added to the DOM, you would be best to use a delegated event handler for this:

```
$('#fromServer').on('click', '#save', saveButtonEventHandler);
```

Comment: Good thing to know about delegated event handlers on jQuery, so you don't have to worry about where to place event handlers for dinamically added DOM elements.

Comment: I chose this answer since it was the first one. Other answer, +1.

Comment: @Ammar what a logic. awesome.

Comment: @nirmal When two identical answers are posted the general guidance is to accept the one posted first.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan am new here can you tell me where I can read general guidance. ?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like content is loaded with ajax.
you can use below function.

```
$(document).on("click", '#save', function(event) { 
    alert("button pressed");
});
```